# Accessing nodes in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am running into a weird problem with accessing nodes in my XML file.

If I do (in my XQuery file) :

```
return <result>$myfile/option[2]</result>
```

It works fine, however, if I try :

```
return <result>$myfile/option[$myfile/data(@index)]</result>
```

It doesn't work. The value of `$myfile/data(@index)` is 2.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've left out the curly braces from these code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The value of `$myfile/data(@index)` is 2

I suspect it is the *string* "2" rather than the *number* 2.  Try casting it

```
return <result>$myfile/option[xs:integer($myfile/data(@index))]</result>
```